# Excel For If not working correctly one one sheet versus other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have this loop that I found that has worked plenty of times in the past. All it does it look at the previous cell and if the value in the cell is different than it will insert a row. The code is below.

```
Dim lr As Integer
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = lr To 2 Step by - 1
    If Cells(i, 8).Value > Cells(i - 1, 8).Value Then
        Cells(i, 8).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What is currently does for this particular sheet is stop after the first iteration and doesn't continue the loop. The column that the code is searching for is the last one (column 8) and the first column is just a list to count the rows from 1 to "lr" (last row).

Example:

[Original sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO7cd.png)

[After the macro is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk9fw.png)

Does anyone know why it stops after the first iteration?

Thanks

Comment: Did you copy and paste your source above or type it? I ask because the code above has a typo in the loop: note the space `Step by - 1`. Same with the cell `Cells(i - 1, 8)`

Comment: The images show the spaces. It inserts a row between row #177 and #176 which corresponds to ID# 176 and 175. I also copied the code from a file I save codes on, so I know it worked before.

Comment: @Alan - oddly enough with     Option Explicit  disabled, that code actually runs. Apparently, *by* is considered an undeclared var that is instantiated as numerically zero so `Step by - 1` is the same as `Step -1`. The `i - 1` is intentional as it refers to the row above i.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out you can't have anything in columns that are after the columns in questions. For example, in here I had other values in cells in column 9 and I was separating by column 8.

Comment: 1. Of course you can have values in columns 9 and higher. 2. You really should fix that For ... Next Step syntax. I'm sure it is going to come back and bite you sometime in the future if you don't.

Comment: @Jeeped @stephen-wyka **by** is not used in Step syntax. It should simply be `For Words = 10 To 1 Step -1` as per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/fornext-statement) which is why it considered by to be a variable and ran with Option Explicit turned off.

Comment: @Jeeped Well spotted on my eyes catching a false match.

Comment: Well I switched the columns and had my search column as the last column and the code worked perfectly, so I don't know. I'll take a look at re-phrasing the code. Thanks